# I can't find the variable that has been declared in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm studying the sources of YouTube Channel.
For the convenience, I had rewrotten the codes of that page simply.
This is the HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<script data-original-src="/miniplayer.js" src="/miniplayer.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

And this is the code of 'miniplayer.js'.

```
(function(g) {
var window = this;
...
})(_yt_player);
```

I think that the 'miniplayer.js' is a first code to be precessed because
it is located at the first line of head tag.
But I can't find the variable '_yt_player' in a function of 'miniplayer.js'
which is executed immediately when the script is called.

Comment: Is there an element with `id="_yt_player"`? Element IDs become global variables.

Answer (score 2):

To find the location where a global object is defined, if the object has functions, usually you can use `console.dir` on the function and examine its `[[FunctionLocation]]` property. This is how I found where the `yt_player` was defined:

[image]

That's the easy method. If that doesn't work, another way to identify where a window property gets created is to use a [userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) which runs at the start of page load, and assigns a *setter* to the property. When the setter is called, throw an error, and examine the stack trace.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Find _yt_player
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

Object.defineProperty(window, '_yt_player', {
  set(newVal) {
    throw new Error('_yt_player was just assigned to');
  }
});
```

[image]

Both methods above take you to `base.js`.

Comment: Oh. So thanks. I found _yt_player too. But I wonder how the variable has been declared. Exactly saying, when _yt_player in base.js was declared. It didn't seem that the base.js is executed at beginning of HTML auto matically because I tried it in my own project.